What is the significance of the Coincidence Lemma?
There is not a Wikipedia article about the coincidence lemma.
I will try to explain the proof and then ask why it is important.

The coincidence lemma is meant to show that the satisfaction relation between a formula and an interpretation only depends on:

the interpretation of the symbols in the formula,
and the free variables in the formula

The proof I am studying begins by declaring 2 interpretations. They are interpretations of different languages, but they have the same domain that they interpret the languages in.

S is specifically the set of function, relation, and constant symbols of a given language - the symbols that generally characterize a given first-order language, because they can vary.
The author takes the intersection of the two symbol sets (which I find odd, in the event that they are disjoint).
a) says that if the two interpretations map the symbols in a term t in exactly the same way, this suffices to know that they are the same interpretation.
b) says that if the two interpretations map the symbols in a formula φ in exactly the same way, this suffices to know that they have the exact same set of formulas which satisfy them.
I think the argument is building up to some way of showing you do not actually need to worry about variable assignments when determining if a structure satisfies a formula.

Second bullet above: variable assignments are defined for all (infinite many) variables of the language but what matters for the satisfaction of a formula are only the free variables in it, I e. only a finite number.
